# Evaluate expression in a string in python

Tags: python-3.x, regex, string, eval, python-re

I have a string with mathematical operations, how do I evaluate the string within `[]` to generate the output shown below?

```
mystring = "[2*3-1] plus [4+2] is equal to [5+6]."

re.findall(r"\[(.*?)\]",mystring) # to find 2*3-1, 4+2, 5+6

Output: "5 plus 6 is equal to 11." # expected output.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `re.sub` with `eval` and a callback function here:

```py
mystring = "[2*3-1] plus [4+2] is equal to [5+6]."
output = re.sub(r'\[(.*?)\]', lambda m: str(eval(m.group(1))), mystring)
print(output)  # 5 plus 6 is equal to 11.
```

The strategy here is to match the aritrmetic expression inside every `[...]`, which then gets passed to a lambda function.  There, we call `eval()` to get the result, cast to a string and generate the replacement.

Comment: ++ but OP doesn't need `[` and `]` in output

Comment: @anubhava On a cell phone with bad visibility to the entire screen at once, sorry.

Comment: You wrote this formatted code on a mobile, wish I could give 10 ++ to you

Comment: Still trying to find a software shop where mobile typing skills gets you promoted `:-)`